# How do I test a function in rust that is using a deadpool-postgres pool in an actix-web based server application?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am building a web server using actix-web (version 3) and deadpool-postgres pool manager to connect to the database. I wanted to create a test for running a stored procedure but I keep getting the error `there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime` when I run `cargo test`
I read somewhere that this is because there are 2 versions of the tokio crate being used so I tried to upgrade actix-web to 4.0.0-beta8 but the error still persists.

```
#[test]
async fn test_sp() {
  // pool setup code here
  let mut client = pool.get().await.unwrap();
  let name: &str = "test_user";
  let rows = client.query("test_user_add", &[&name]).await.unwrap(); 
}
```

Comment: strange that your function is not async

Comment: I did try using ```tokio::test``` as well and using async function but it throws the same error.

Comment: please don't change your question to include my answer, making my answer wrong.

Comment: how am I supposed to show that I tried using an async function?

Comment: First, you just not only add async, that could be ok, but you added `tokio::test`, thus COMPLETELY change your question, you could ask another question. or improve this one to contain a full [mcve] of your first version because as I said, "strange that your function is not async" your code as presented here CAN'T compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tokio reactor runtine, tokio have a tool for test function:

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn my_test() {
    assert!(true);
}
```

be sure to read the [documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/attr.test.html).

Comment: I did try using ```tokio::test``` and making it an async function but it throws the same error.

Comment: @ferdtomale if you use actix 4 that should not happen, guess you will have to ask on github issue of actix